# No route matches [GET] "/controller/method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to call a controller action on the link on rails app.

The controller action basically creates a new phone number and generates a Twilio pin.

**controller**

```
def resend
      @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number])
      @phone_number.generate_pin
      @phone_number.send_pin
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js # render app/views/phone_numbers/create.js.erb
      end
end
```

**view**

`<a href="<%= phone_numbers_resend_path %>">Resend Pin</a>`

**routes.rb**`

`post 'phone_numbers/resend' => "phone_numbers#resend"`

So when I click "Resend Pin". I am getting

`No route matches [GET] "/phone_numbers/resend"`

**rake routes** output

```
phone_numbers POST /phone_numbers(.:format)        phone_numbers#create
    new_phone_number GET  /phone_numbers/new(.:format)    phone_numbers#new
phone_numbers_verify POST /phone_numbers/verify(.:format) phone_numbers#verify
phone_numbers_resend POST /phone_numbers/resend(.:format) phone_numbers#resend
```

In routes, I have set it as a post. Why am I getting this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to "Send Pin", phone_numbers_resend_path, method: :post
```

Comment: I updated question with `rake routes` output please check.

Comment: well i got it, the normal clicking to a normal a tag will make a get request to href value (e.g. example.com/phone_numbers/resend), but you have defined that path for post - not for get. so, you should rewrite it as I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

`Anchor tag(<a>)` by default uses `get` request . But in routes, you are using `post` method. So, to make it working you can do any one of the below:

```
<%= link_to 'Resend Pin', phone_numbers_resend_path, method: :post %>

                        or

get 'phone_numbers/resend' => "phone_numbers#resend"
```